# Unable to connect to Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL) instance with Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I am simply not able to establish a connection to my Cloud SQL instance (PostreSQL). For deployment, I have created a cloudbuild.yamlbut no matter what I try, I'm not able to connect.

For now, I am just creating a .env during a build step. I am aware that this is not safe. I'm intending to fix this later on.

```yaml
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        echo "ENVIRONMENT=development" > .env
        echo "DB_HOST=12.34.56.78 >> .env
        echo "DB_NAME=my-database-dev" >> .env
        echo "DB_USERNAME=postgres" >> .env
        echo "DB_PASSWORD=password" >> .env
        echo "DB_DIALECT=postgres" >> .env
        echo "CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE="$_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE >> .env

  # Step to install dependencies
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: [ 'install' ]
  # Step to apply Sequelize migrations
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: [ 'run', 'db:migrate' ]
```

As I am calling gcloud builds submit . I am getting to the following error-response. Note, that I am doing this with my own account, not a Service Account. I am owner of the project but I added Cloud SQL Admin for good measure to my roles for now.

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.cloud.sql.v1beta4.SqlConnectService.GetConnectSettings",
          "service": "sqladmin.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't understand why I get this error and how to fix this.

Additionally, I'd like to highlight that I am not available to connect to the database using psql. Perhaps, this is expected, but in trying to get any connection going, I tried to rune psql -h postgresql://user:password@public-ip/database-name but only got a timeout from that.

Last but not least, since I am using Sequelize, this is how I am initializing it:

```js
const connector = new Connector();
const clientOpts = connector.getOptions({
  instanceConnectionName: process.env.CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE,
  ipType: IpAddressTypes.PUBLIC,
  authType: process.env.DB_PASSWORD ? AuthTypes.PASSWORD : AuthTypes.IAM,
});
dbConfig = {
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
  dialectOptions: clientOpts,
};
export const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  ...dbConfig,
  models: [/* ... */],
});

// Test connection
try {
  console.log('[sequelize.ts] Testing connection ..');
  sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .catch((err) => console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err))
    .then();
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
}
```

In general, I am able to connect locally via the `gcloud sql` command:

```bash
$ gcloud sql connect myproject-postgres-dev --user=postgres
```

It's not clear to me whether I am doing something wrong here in general, or whether there's an issue with Sequelize.

Can somebody please guide me though this?

Comment: Have you tried the solution from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56231361/18265570)? Also check [this link](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Databases/How-to-connect-Sequelize-to-cloud-sql-nodejs-connector/).

Comment: @RoopaM Thank you, but I was able to solve the issue. Didn't have time to post an answer yet. The problem was/is that `connector.getOptions()` returns a promise which I had to await for. I assumed that this will be done for me but as it turns out, the constructor is fully synchronous. As such, I converted my entire project to use ESM s.t. I can use top-level `await`. With that the problem was resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

When an application connects to Cloud SQL using the Cloud SQL Connector, it needs two sets of credentials:

- The Postgresql database username and password. Your code appears to handle this correctly.
- The Google Cloud Application Default credentials. This is usually configured using Google Cloud IAM.

Since this code is running in a Cloud Build job, you need to grant the SQL Client role (`roles/cloudsql.client`) to the Cloud Build service account. [Configure Access for the Cloud Build Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-for-cloud-build-service-account) help article describes how to do this in detail.